# ssis XML source converting UTC to local time

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package with

XMLSource as source and the output is writing it to the table.

> XMLSource ->Table (with Date coloumn)

The problem is the XML file has datetime values in UTC like

> 2011-03-27T04:00:00Z

when the SSIS parse it, it is changing it to local time. But i dont want this to happen. i.e.
SSIS should not convert the datetime in the XML to local time. how to stop this conversion.
Any one having similar experience. please help.